# Getting "CRC check failed" when installing python using chef

Tags: python, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm trying to install graphite using chef-solo and vagrant onto a 64-bit lucid VM. One of graphite's dependencies is python and when I try to provision the VM I'm getting the error below. I'm using the standard python cookbook from Opscode (https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/python)

I'm not familiar with chef or python so this error has me a bit stumped. Any help appreciated.

```
[default] Running provisioner: Vagrant::Provisioners::ChefSolo...
[default] Generating chef JSON and uploading...
[default] Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[2013-03-11T00:18:05+01:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.14.2 ***
[2013-03-11T00:18:05+01:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[graphite]"] from JSON
[2013-03-11T00:18:05+01:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[graphite]]
[2013-03-11T00:18:05+01:00] INFO: Run List expands to [graphite]
[2013-03-11T00:18:05+01:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for lucid64.hsd1.ca.comcast.net.
[2013-03-11T00:18:05+01:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2013-03-11T00:18:05+01:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2013-03-11T00:18:06+01:00] WARN: This recipe uses encrypted data bags, which are not supported on Chef Solo - fallback to node attribute.
[2013-03-11T00:18:06+01:00] INFO: Processing package[python] action install (python::package line 40)
[2013-03-11T00:18:06+01:00] INFO: Processing package[python-dev] action install (python::package line 40)
[2013-03-11T00:18:06+01:00] INFO: Processing remote_file[/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/distribute_setup.py] action create (python::pip line 33)
[2013-03-11T00:18:06+01:00] INFO: Processing execute[install-pip] action run (python::pip line 39)

================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[install-pip]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '127'
---- Begin output of   /usr/bin/python distribute_setup.py --download-base=https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/
  /usr/local/bin/easy_install pip
 ----
STDOUT: Extracting in /tmp/tmphzwy_0
STDERR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 546, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 543, in main
    return _install(tarball, _build_install_args(options))
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 77, in _install
    _extractall(tar)
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 479, in _extractall
    for tarinfo in members:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/tarfile.py", line 2412, in next
    tarinfo = self.tarfile.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/tarfile.py", line 2314, in next
    self.fileobj.seek(self.offset)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/gzip.py", line 382, in seek
    self.read(1024)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/gzip.py", line 219, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/gzip.py", line 267, in _read
    self._read_eof()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/gzip.py", line 304, in _read_eof
    hex(self.crc)))
IOError: CRC check failed 0x94c615b3 != 0x2e611106L
sh: /usr/local/bin/easy_install: not found
---- End output of   /usr/bin/python distribute_setup.py --download-base=https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/
  /usr/local/bin/easy_install pip
 ----
Ran   /usr/bin/python distribute_setup.py --download-base=https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/
  /usr/local/bin/easy_install pip
 returned 127
```

Comment: Have you installed `easy_install`?

Comment: @grc I suppose `/usr/bin/python distribute_setup.py` does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

The error `IOError: CRC check failed 0x94c615b3 != 0x2e611106L` indicates that the gzip module is failing to extract the downloaded .tgz file. This could be caused by network issues.

To isolate this issue, try running the command to setup distribute manually, i.e. run `vagrant ssh` and then:

```
/usr/bin/python distribute_setup.py --download-base=https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/
```

This should help you to narrow down where in the distribute_setup.py file the process has gone wrong. If distribute_setup.py fails, then you can inspect the distribute-X.Y.Z.tar.gz file that it downloaded to see if it matches the one at https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/ (take the md5sum of both files to verify that they are the same). If they are the same, I'd try extracting the .tgz that was just downloaded manually to see if it's valid; I suppose it's conceivable that one of the files on the site is corrupt, although that seems unlikely.

If a solution is not immediately apparent at this point, update your question with these extra diags and we'll see what further digging can be done.